# android - edittext lost focus to listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

**solved**: [android - edittext lost focus to listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839786/android-edittext-lost-focus-to-listview#comment38576247_24839786)

in my app i'm trying to insert data into database and retrieve them and show on listview

i have a relative layout and 2 edittext and one listview with custom adapter for showing two columns of data in listview 
edittext are in top and listview is in bottom of screen
i override edittext onkey methods for check if user press enter key then if on edittext1 then edittext2 requestfocus and if on edittext2 then insert data to database retrieve data from database and fill the listview after that back focus to edittext2 and continue this loop

BUT, after insert one row when press enter key on edittext1 focus go to edittext2 and jump very fast to listview first item !!!! i can back focus with tap edittext2 but this shouldn't happen

i check my code i just pass request focus between two edittext no list view 
what should i do ?

edit 1:
i use custom edit text extends class work on one activity but not work on all then the problem not solved

when i try to change focus from one edittext to another edittext the first item of listview capture the focus and highlight

Comment: use customized edittext class your focus changing event will defiantly captured and after that let me inform

Comment: @Rajajisubramanian thanks my custom edittext work well, thank you

Comment: nope the problem back again in another same activity!!!! i don't know why ?!

Comment: ok again this solve with use lv.setFocusable(false); lv.setFocusableInTouchMode(false); lv.setItemsCanFocus(false); before and after set adapter ;)

Comment: put upvote form my any other question in my profile which you like dude